# Were "spring-heeled boots" a real thing, and if so, what did they look like?

Tags: clothing, victorian, popular-culture

Dylan Thomas's "The Peaches" (from *Portrait of the Artist as a Young Dog*, 1940):

> The passage grew dark too suddenly, the walls crowded in, and the roofs crouched down. To me, staring timidly there in the dark passage in a strange town, the swarthy man appeared like a giant in a cage surrounded by clouds, and the bald old man withered into a black hump with a white top; two white hands darted out of the corner with invisible cards. A man with **spring-heeled boots** and a two-edged knife might be bouncing towards me from Union Street.

Tim Powers' *The Anubis Gates* (1989) [[1]](https://books.google.com/books?id=BvYaur1vHM0C&q=spring):

> Now that the cloak was gone everyone could see the **spring-soled shoes** that he bobbed up and down on.

These of course are references to "[Spring-heeled Jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring-heeled_Jack)," the Victorian bogeyman, who — if I understand correctly — was supposed to have some sort of springs in his bootheels that allowed him to jump over tall buildings in a single bound. (Maybe not on his first appearances in the 1830s, but certainly by the 1860s this seems to be the pop-cultural image.) So the notion of "boots with springs in the heels" is floating around Victorian-and-later pop culture. I'm trying to get a mental image of what this actually means.

- Was there a *real* fashion trend along the lines of "spring-shoes" in the 19th century? (Platform shoes certainly existed. And just because some accessory sounds over-the-top implausible doesn't mean it didn't happen; [sword-sticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swordstick) were a real thing, for example.)
- Or were spring-heeled boots more like [jetpacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_pack), in that anyone from the 1930s could draw you a picture of a jetpack and tell you what it did, *but* it just happened not to exist in the real world?
- Or was "spring-heel" more of a completely linguistic phenomenon without a concrete technological image to go with it? (I have no great analogy/example for this.)

Comment: Certainly they existed: See [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spring%20heel) and thousands of [newspaper results](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/search/pages/results/?state=&date1=1866&date2=1941&proxtext=%22spring-heeled+shoes%22&x=15&y=19&dateFilterType=yearRange&rows=20&searchType=basic). None of them actually explain what it looks like, though.

Comment: [spring heeled boots](https://forestnet.com/timberwest/archives/Nov_Dec_04/history.htm), but probably not what was referenced. I incline to the "jetpack" hypothesis. Physics suggests that this is a dream, not a reality.  Not my field, but I shudder to think about the materials science or the guidance/control.

Comment: Jackie Chan [can do that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5A5E8erk_Eg) without any special equipment.

Comment: The modern version is made by Z-Coil: https://zcoil.com/aussie-black/  Their shoes have an exposed coil spring, but the boots seem to have room to conceal the coil. Obviously not what was written about 100-150 years ago...

Comment: @MCW Some of the results linked to by CDR are newspaper advertisements for such shoes.

Answer (score 5):

US patent number [6610](https://image-ppubs.uspto.gov/dirsearch-public/print/downloadPdf/0006610) (pdf), issued July 24, 1849, to Patrick S. Devlan for a Metallic Spring Heel, opens with the following paragraph:

> Be it known that I, Patrick S. Devlan, of Reading, in the county of Berks and State of Pennsylvania, have invented a new and useful Metallic Spring-Heel for Boots and Shoes, of which the following is a full and exact description...

The patent includes illustrations showing how the spring fits within the heel (click to enlarge).

[image: patent for Metallic Spring Heel]

Comment: Were these ever produced, popular, or even functional? For comparison, the first jet pack patent was issued for a design from *over a hundred years ago*, but that is of course not evidence that functional jet packs existed at that time.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie, oh, so cynical! :)